# Make funnel edges smooth?

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts, plotly, plotly.js

I’ve read every property of the schema for the funnel types, but I can’t seem to grasp how would you make smoother edges for a `funnel` type chart? (not a `funnelarea`)

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this? Even if it’s a hack or a workaround, anything goes,

[image: plotly js funnel chart with no smooth edges]

Comment: I don't think this feature is possible in plotly unless you want to build the `funnel` chart from scratch – the best you could probably do is add circular shapes to each layer of the funnel, but this probably won't look very good and also potentially misrepresents the relative proportion of the data as it makes the areas of the data at end of of every layer larger

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the chart in the image, you can use the Highcharts `columnrange` series for this.

Here is the example config:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  },

  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        align: 'center',
        inside: true,
        formatter() {
          return Math.abs(this.point.low - this.point.high)
        }
      },
      grouping: false,
      groupPadding: 0,
      pointPadding: 0,
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
        low: 0,
        high: 20
      },
      {
        low: 10,
        high: 20
      },
      {
        low: 15,
        high: 25
      }
    ]
  }, {
    data: [{
        low: 20,
        high: 35
      },
      {
        low: 20,
        high: 30
      },
      {
        low: 25,
        high: 30
      }
    ]
  }, {
    data: [{
        low: 35,
        high: 50
      },
      {
        low: 30,
        high: 40
      },
      {
        low: 30,
        high: 35
      }
    ]
  }]
});
```

When it comes to the `dataLabels`, I'm not quite sure how the percents should be calculate for your example but for all calculations you can use the `dataLabels.formatter()`.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6arb34q1/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter